# OpenMPI program with scanf does not work

Tags: c, openmpi

I am trying to send an input message, but my program hangs

```
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc,char* argv[]){
int mi_rango;
int p;
int fuente;
int dest;
int etiqueta=0;
char mensaje[100] ;
MPI_Status status;

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&mi_rango);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&p);

if(mi_rango==0){

    printf("Ingrese la expresión a evaluar: ");
    scanf("%s", mensaje);


    for(fuente=1;fuente<p;fuente++){
               MPI_Send(mensaje,strlen(mensaje)+1,MPI_CHAR,fuente,etiqueta,MPI_COMM_WORLD); 

   }

}else{

dest=0;
MPI_Recv(mensaje,100,MPI_CHAR,dest,etiqueta,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    printf("%s\n",mensaje); 

 }
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

When I run: mpirun -np 3 --hostfile ./program  It does not do anything. 
When I send a message defined in the program  it works.

Comment: You *do* provide some input for `scanf` to read? Have you tried to step through the code in a debugger to see *where* it "hangs"?

Comment: When I run the program , it does not print anything, and If I type something (for example 'hello')and press enter it prints: Ingrese la expresión a evaluar: hello and thats all

Comment: You might want to [*flush*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) the output before getting the input.

Comment: yes, that works thanks